# mod_rewrite from .php to .html for web crawlers

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using mod_rewrite in .htaccess to redirect from .php to .html like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+).html$ /$1.php [QSA,L]
```

It works in a web browser, but **Google is crawling the old URLs** i.e. `index.php` and `faq.php`.

How I can redirect the `index.php` to `index.html`? My website URL is: http://www.21flats.com/.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you're not using php, then just change the extensions of your files. Is there a particular reason why you're approaching it this way?

Comment: Hi Rgin, At website I have changed the extensions, but the problem is in those which has been crawled by google. and this I want to do for SEO purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Add `[QSA,L,R=301]` so Google will see that there has been a redirect. This adds a 301 redirect to the rewrite for search engines:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1.html [QSA,R=301,L]
```

You have the redirect backwards, so change it and add the 301 rule and you are good.

Comment: But adding this url is not redirecting to .html. It changed all to .php

Comment: By adding this, browser shoews the error : **The page isn't redirecting properly**
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Its doing the same job, as I explained. Actually I want to change url dynamically. I a user click on index.php, he redirected to index.html